# How To Send An Instance To a Partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, web-applications, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a partial that can be used throughout my app. When I try and load the page I get this error:

```
NameError in Home#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/shared/_avatar.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method user for #<#<Class:0x007f9ce4f05ef0>:0x007f9ce5b9c920>
Extracted source (around line #3):

<div class="avatar-circle">
   <span class="initials">
     <%= user.full_name[0..1].upcase %>
   </span>
</div>
```

Here is my code:
app/views/home/index.html.erb:

```
<%= show_avatar(post.user) %>
```

app/controllers/concerns/users_helper.rb:

```
def show_avatar(user)
  if user.avatar?
    image_tag(user.avatar, class: 'avatar-circle')
  else
    render partial: 'shared/avatar', :user => user
  end
end
```

app/views/shared/_avatar.html.erb:

```
<%= user.full_name[0..1].upcase %>
```

app/models/user.rb:

```
def full_name
  return "#{first_name} #{last_name}".strip if (first_name || last_name)
end
```

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be grateful, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How one can actually do such things:

You create instance variable in your controller's action. Like this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: 1)
  end
end
```

`@user` variable now can be used from the view `users/show.html.erb`

You can render certain partial from your view and pass `@user` variable to it:

```
<%= render partial: 'partial_name', locals: {user: @user}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line in your concern:

```
render partial: 'shared/avatar', locals: { user: user }
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables to a partial you need to do like this:

```
render partial: 'shared/avatar', locals: {:user => user}
```